# How to update the props of a component in a list of components

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to update a prop value of a component in a list of components. Following is an example of it.

I'm developing an app using ReactNative

```js
...
constructor(props) {
state = {
  components: [*list of components*],
}
componentDidMount() {
  fetchingAPI().then(response => {
    const components = [];
    for (const data of response.data) {
      components.push(<MyComponent numOfLike={data.numOfLike} />);
    }

    this.setState({components});
  });
}
render() {
  return (
    ...
    {this.state.components}
    ...
  );
}
```

When I want to update a component, I update the whole state named components like :

```js
updateAComponent(index, newNumOfLike) {
  const components = this.state.components;

  components[index] = <MyComponent numOfLike={newNumOfLike} />

  this.setState({components});
}
```

But, this method change the component, not update. right? I means the `components` state is updated but `MyComponent` in `components[index]` is changed.

So, if I want to **update** the `MyComponent` in `components[index]` using the way of **update** the props `numOfLike` directly, how can I do it?

**addition** :

What I did not mention is that the `MyComponent` has a `Image` tag in it. So if I use `FlatList` or `array.prototype.map` there are several issues.

1. If I update the state, the whole list will be re-rendered. So if there are many list item, the speed of updating is very slow.
2. Since there are `Image` tag in the list, if I update a list item, the whole `Image` tags blink since the list items are re-rendered.

In this situation

1. Is there way to re-render(update) only a component which I want to update? (target updating)
2. If there in no way to target updating, just let the whole list items(components) re-rendered when just a component is updated?

Comment: why don't you use `FlatList`. I suggest use just store response data in `state`. Then in `render` method, you can populate your view base on your data

Comment: It would be easier to keep only data in state and then render them with map function

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setNativeProps`, described in the [direct manipulation documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/direct-manipulation)

```js
components[index].setNativeProps(propsObj)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. But I can use the `setNativeProps` method on `MyComponent`. `MyComponent` has no such method. How can I use it? do you have an example on it?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your `componentDidMount` function like this (so that there are no race around or async conditions in the code) -:

```
componentDidMount() {
  fetchingAPI().then(response => {
    this.setState({
        components: this.state.components.concat(
               response.data.map(i => <MyComponent numOfLike={i.numOfLike} />)
        )});
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with the `FlatList`?

eg:

```
...
constructor(props) {
state = {
  componentsData: [],
}

componentDidMount() {
  fetchingAPI().then(response => {
    this.setState({componentsData: response.data});
  });
}

_renderItems = ({ item, index }) => {

  return(
    <MyComponent numOfLike={item. numOfLike} />
  )
} 

render() {
  return (
    ...
    <FlatList
       data={this.state.componentsData}
       renderItem={this._renderItems}
       keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
       extraData={this.state}
    />
    ...
  );
}
```

Then when you want to update the list,

```
updateAComponent(index, newNumOfLike) {
  const data = this.state.componentsData;
  data[index].numOfLike = newNumOfLike
  this.setState({componentsData: data});
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. And I have a question. Actually the `MyComponent` has a `Image` tag. So there are two issues here. 1. When I update the state, the whole list item is updated. So if there are many items, the speed of updating is very slow. 2. Since updating the state will update the whole FlatList items, the `Image` tags blinks after updating. **Is there any way to update a certain component ?**

Comment: Can you use pure component in render item?